# Set up multiple subplots with moving averages using cufflinks and plotly offline

Tags: python, plotly, offline, subplot, moving-average

Im trying to select 4 different product prices from my dataframe and plot their moving average as a subplot (2,2) using plotly cufflinks. I would appreciate if anyone can guide on this.

I tried plotting the price as below. 
I came across cufflinks technical analysis which allow me to plot moving average in a cleaner way, however, im not too sure how to apply it yet.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
from plotly import tools
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1= go.Scatter(name=',milk', x=df.Date, y=df['milk'])
trace2= go.Scatter(name='soap', x=df.Date, y=df['soap'])
trace3= go.Scatter(name='rice', x=df.Date, y=df['rice'])
trace4= go.Scatter(name='water', x=df.Date, y=df['water'])

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=('milk', 'soap',
                                                      'rice', 'water'))
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 1, 2)
fig.append_trace(trace3, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace4, 2, 2)

fig['layout'].update(height=1000, width=1800, title='supermarket')

plot(fig, filename='supermarket.html')
```

I would appreciate if someone could teach me how to use plotly cufflinks to plot  four moving averages from the selected columns from a dataframe using plotly offline.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! I like your question and the fact that you've made some real effort here. You will however increase your chances of receiving answers considerably if you're able to provide some sample data and also try to follow the other guidelines on [How do I ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) When you receive a hopefully useful answer, please consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Insert the code section below in a Jupyter Notebook to produce the following plot using cufflinks and plotly offline:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import plotly
from plotly import tools
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import copy
import plotly.graph_objs as go

####### PART 1 - SETUP AND SAMPLE DATA #######
# setup
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:55% !important; } .widget-select > select {background-color: gainsboro;}</style>"))
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines().iloc[:,0:4]
df.columns = ['StockA', 'StockB', 'StockC', 'StockD']

####### PART 2 - FUNCTION FOR MOVING AVERAGES #######

# Function for moving averages
def movingAvg(df, win, keepSource):
    """Add moving averages for all columns in a dataframe.

    Arguments: 
    df -- pandas dataframe
    win -- length of movingAvg estimation window
    keepSource -- True or False for keep or drop source data in output dataframe

    """

    df_temp = df.copy()
    # Manage existing column names
    colNames = list(df_temp.columns.values).copy()
    removeNames = colNames.copy()

    i = 0
    for col in colNames:
        # Make new names for movingAvgs
        movingAvgName = colNames[i] + '_MA' #+ str(win)   
        # Add movingAvgs
        df_temp[movingAvgName] = df[col].rolling(window=win).mean()


        i = i + 1

    # Remove estimates with insufficient window length
    df_temp = df_temp.iloc[win:]

    # Remove or keep source data
    if keepSource == False:
        df_temp = df_temp.drop(removeNames,1)
    return df_temp

# Add moving averages to df
windowLength = 10
df = movingAvg(df=df, win=windowLength, keepSource = True)

####### PART 3 -PLOTLY RULES #######
# Structure lines / traces for the plots
# trace 1
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockA'],
    name='StockA'
)

trace1_ma = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockA_MA'],
    name='StockA_MA'
)

# trace 2
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockB'],
    name='StockB'

)
trace2_ma = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockB_MA'],
    name='StockB_MA'
)

# trace 3
trace3 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockC'],
    name='StockC'
)

trace3_ma = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockC_MA'],
    name='StockC_MA'
)

# trace 4
trace4 = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockD'],
    name='StockD'
)

trace4_ma = go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['StockD_MA'],
    name='StockD_MA'
)

# Structure traces as datasets
data1 = [trace1, trace1_ma]
data2 = [trace2, trace2_ma]
data3 = [trace3, trace3_ma]
data4 = [trace4, trace4_ma]

# Build figures
fig1 = go.Figure(data=data1)
fig2 = go.Figure(data=data2)
fig3 = go.Figure(data=data3)
fig4 = go.Figure(data=data4)

# Subplots setup and layout
figs = cf.subplots([fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4],shape=(2,2))
figs['layout'].update(height=800, width=1200,
                      title='Stocks with moving averages = '+ str(windowLength))

iplot(figs)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi vestland thanks for your answer, i came across this https://plot.ly/pandas/moving-average/ and the code used was 
    cf.datagen.lines(1,500).ta_plot(study='sma',periods=[13,21,55],title='Simple Moving Averages') , any chance you know how to implement into the above to simplify the code? thanks